# Partial specialization of nested class on enum defined inside a template class

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer, partial-specialization

Please see the following code:

```
template <class T>
struct X {
  enum class E { e0 };

  template <class U, E e>
  struct Y {};

  template <class U>
  struct Y<U, E::e0> {
    static int f() { return 0; }
  };
};

int main() {
  X<int>::Y<int, X<int>::E::e0>::f();
}
```

VC++ 15.7.5 generates an error message:

```
1>  test.cpp
1>  some_directory\test.cpp(15): error C2039: 'f': is not a member of 'X<int>::Y<int,X<int>::E::e0>'
1>  some_directory\test.cpp(15): note: see declaration of 'X<int>::Y<int,X<int>::E::e0>'
1>  some_directory\test.cpp(15): error C3861: 'f': identifier not found
```

However, GCC & Clang seem to accept this code.

Which one is correct?

### EDIT

On older version of VC++ generates the following error message:

```
source_file.cpp(9): error C2754: 'X<T>::Y<U,>': a partial specialization cannot have a dependent non-type template parameter
source_file.cpp(12): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'X<T>' being compiled
source_file.cpp(16): error C2039: 'f': is not a member of 'X<int>::Y<int,X<int>::E::e0>'
source_file.cpp(16): error C3861: 'f': identifier not found
```

So I think the reason VC++ refuses to compile is that `enum class E` is defined inside a template class. Indeed, the error disappears (both in the old version and the recent 15.7.5) if I move `enum class E` outside `X`.

Is this case really a case of partial specialization on a dependent non-type template parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC and Clang are correct to accept it. This is all according to [[temp.class.spec]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class.spec#5), which also has a supporting example:

> A class template partial specialization may be declared in any scope
>   in which the corresponding primary template may be defined
>   ([namespace.memdef], [class.mem], [temp.mem]). [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct A {
>   struct C {
>     template<class T2> struct B { };
>     template<class T2> struct B<T2**> { };      // partial specialization #1
>   };
> };
>
> // partial specialization of A<T>​::​C​::​B<T2>
> template<class T> template<class T2>
>   struct A<T>::C::B<T2*> { };                   // #2
>
> A<short>::C::B<int*> absip;                     // uses partial specialization #2
> ```
>
> — end example ]

A workaround with MSVC may be to try and specialize the member template at namespace scope.

---

As for your edit, I would say MSVC is still wrong. The relevant standardese is at [[temp.class.spec]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class.spec#8):

> Within the argument list of a class template partial specialization,
>   the following restrictions apply:
>
> - The type of a template parameter corresponding to a specialized non-type argument shall not be dependent on a parameter of the
>     specialization. [ Example:
>
>   ```
>   template <class T, T t> struct C {};
>   template <class T> struct C<T, 1>;              // error
>
>   template< int X, int (*array_ptr)[X] > class A {};
>   int array[5];
>   template< int X > class A<X,&array> { };        // error
>   ```
>
>   — end example ]

Applying it to your example in `struct Y<U, E::e0>`: does the type of the enumeration depend on another template argument to `Y`? The answer is no. It certainly depends on `X<T>`, but that is **another** template specialization. Not the same template we are partially specializing when writing our definition.

Comment: It seems that my question was not so clear. Sorry. Could you see my edit? Thank you.

Comment: So the only issue is whether or not ````e```` is dependent on ````U````,not ````T````. Thanks!